# Browser Sync CLI, watches from NPX but not from package.json

Tags: npm, livereload

I think I'm issuing the equivalent command...

From npx, it runs the server & watches:

`npx browser-sync start --server src/ --files 'src/*.html' 'src/css/*.css' 'src/js/*.js'`

From package.json, it runs server but not watches (doesn't respond to file changes):

`"serve": "browser-sync start --server src/ --files 'src/*.html' 'src/css/*.css' 'src/js/*.js'",`

`npm run serve`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be with quoting. Use `\"` instead of `'`

Instead of...
 `"serve": "browser-sync start --server src/ --files 'src/*.html' 'src/css/*.css' 'src/js/*.js'",`

Use...
`"serve": "browser-sync start --server src/ --files \"src/*.html\" \"src/css/*.css\" \"src/js/*.js\"",`